# discord.py | How to send message to the owner of every guild my bot is in

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

so I want to ask is there a way I can like make a command like when I invoke it, the bot sends a dm to the owner of every guild my bot is in containing my message or it could send that message to the staff only channel of every guild it is in. I could use this command for announcements and stuff.

Comment: Could you please show what have you got so far?

Comment: `@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def broadcast(ctx, message):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if(channel.name == 'general'):
                await channel.send(message)`

Comment: this searches through every guild and if it finds the channel name "general" in any server it sends the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly message a member, you need to obtain the `dm_channel` of the `member` object. You can achieve this by using `member.dm_channel`. Simply use `guild.owner` as the `member` and use the dm-channel to send the message.
You should have `discord.Intents.guild` and `discord.Intents.members` enabled in order for your bot to obtain `guild.owner`.

---

```
@client.command() 
@commands.is_owner() 
async def broadcast(ctx, message):     
    for guild in client.guilds:
        # get the owner of guild
        owner = guild.owner

        # check if dm exists, if not create it
        if owner.dm_channel is None:
            await owner.create_dm()
      
        # if creation of dm successful
        if owner.dm_channel != None:
            await owner.dm_channel.send(message)
   
        for channel in guild.channels:             
            if(channel.name == 'general'):                 
                await channel.send(message)
```